# binding ajax function with "live" gives error, yet works with "click"

Tags: ajax, onclick, jquery

In this function, when I use it I get error on the whole code block! (in chrome console)
however when I replace `live` with `click` it works fine, how is it?

```
$("form[0] :submit").live(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var search_data = { company : $("form[0] :text").val() }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= site_url('pages/search') ?>",
        data: search_data,
        success: function(msg){
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried `$("form[0]").live("submit",function(event...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.live()`, you have to specify which kind of event you want to bind a handler for.  For most situations, it looks like this:

```
$('form[0]').live('submit', function() {
  ...
});
```

You can also use a space-separated list of event types, or an object with event type : function pairs for multiple events / functions.